# Excel "0" and "-" removal to have a non-valued cell

Tags: excel

I am currently working a worksheet that have thousands of data points in which I somehow auto populated blank cells with "0" when the cells should have been blank to begin with. Sadly I don't have time to go through and remove them all by hand.

Tried using formulas that don't account for 0, but that doesn't work. Tried the find and replace function, but that removes the 0's within numbered data points.

How do I remove the cells that contain 0 as their value from these sheets? All my data points have a value of >0.

Comment: Find that matches entire cell contents?

Comment: Do these cells actually have a `0` inside? Or a formula? If it's a zero, just do as nbayly's answer.

Comment: What about those "-" in the title? Are they also cells simply with a hyphen? Of course the same method applies in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a find and replace for "0" and replace with empty field and check the "Match entire cell contents" field as well as set "Look in" set to "Formulas" to not delete formulas which simply output as per suggestions in the comments. That will find cells that have only "0" and not remove a zero from say "500".

Comment: You should add to do this with "Look in" set to "Formulas" to not delete formulas which simply output 0 ;)